# How to verify the certificates of my SSL forward proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate, omniauth

Guy,

I have a problem of accessing `www.googleapis.com` on one of my internal server. I am using `omniauth-google-oauth2` on the Rails application on that server. The connection problem makes the fetch to user raw info api to `www.googleapis.com` to fail.

So I setup an nginx proxy server to proxy the SSL request to `www.googleapis.com`.

My nginx server configuration is like the following:

```
    server {
        listen       443;
        ssl          on;
        server_name  rome.jianshu.io;

        ssl_certificate      ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  ssl/server.key;
        ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass       https://www.googleapis.com$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host      $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_buffering  off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_read_timeout 120s;
            proxy_send_timeout 120s;
        }
    ...
}
```

`server.crt` & `server.key` are generated by myself on the server. And then I change the `/etc/hosts` on my Dev machine to point `www.googleapis.com` to the proxy server api.

The proxy server works well, but I got the problem of verifying the certifications. I got the following exception on my dev manchine:

`Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed at /users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

I know I could bypass it with: `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`, but as this is a highly unsecured solution. I would like to ask you guys, what I could do to my app/prd server/proxy server to make this right?

Comment: Hi, can you share how you solved this?

Comment: @LeoGallucci at last I setup a `tinyproxy` and tell Faraday to use it as the proxy, then it's OK. I was thinking too complicated then.